# XCode GCC-4.0 vs 4.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, objective-c++

I have just changed a compiler option from 4.0 to 4.2.

Now I get an error:

```
jump to case label crosses initialization of 'const char* selectorName'
```

It works fine in 4.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not "just" a warning ? Either way you should fix the bug in your code and/or post the actual code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just a guess* -  you declare variable (probably `const char*`) inside 1 of your switch-case statements - you should wrap that case in {} to fix that.

```
// error
case 1:
   const char* a = ... 
   break; 

// OK
case 1:{
   const char* a = ... 
}
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably declare a variable inside a case without wrapping it all in a brace:

```
case foo:
    const char* selectorName;
    // ...
    break;
```

Should be:

```
case foo: {
    const char* selectorName;
    // ...
    break;
}
```